# How to change Background color of HTML DOC using AJAX Post Request:

Tags: php, html, ajax, background-color

I am trying to create an HTML document that contains a button “Request color”. Whenever a user clicks on “Request color”, the page performs an Ajax POST request to the URL color-service.php. The color-service.php file handles the POST request and returns a JSON containing a random color, for example: { color: "red" }. The Ajax response is then used to change the background of the color.html page accordingly.

Current HTML:

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Random Color Changer</title>
</head>

<body style="<? echo $color?>">
    <h1>Random Color Generator</h1>
    <p id="color"></p>
    <button type="button" onclick="changeColor()">Request Color</button>
    <script>

        function changecolor() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById.color = this.responseText;
    }
        }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "color-service.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Current PHP:

```
<?php
    $list = array('red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'pink', 'green');

$i = array_rand($list);
$color = $list[$i];
?>
```

Comment: "The color-service.php file handles the POST request and returns a JSON containing a random color" — No, it doesn't. It doesn't output anything,

Comment: echo json_encode(array('color'=>$list[$i]));

Comment: You are callilng changeColor() with uppercase C while the function name is changecolor(). Now you forgot to mention what is not working (if this doesn't already fix it)

Answer (score 0):

```
<body style="background-color:<? echo $color?>">
```

Make sure you're using `background-color` otherwise the browser won't know what you want coloured and in order for `$color` to do anything, you need to define it before you use it in your HTML.

```
 echo $color = $list[$i];
```

And make sure color-serivce.php actually returns the random colour using `echo`, otherwise it will just be a blank page.

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.responseText;
```

The JavaScript attribute you need to use is `.style.backgroundColor` and you need to use  otherwise the browser doesn't know what you want coloured. Just `color` on it's own won't work for what you want it to (it will set the colour of the text).

Also you've give your function two different names; in one case it says `changeColor()` and in another it doesn't have the capital 'C'.

Answer (score -1):

There are several problems here, but what you want is this:

HTML

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Random Color Changer</title>
</head>

<body id="fillme">
    <h1>Random Color Generator</h1>
    <p id="color"></p>
    <script>
        function changecolor() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.open("GET", "color-service.php", true);
            xhttp.onload = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('fillme').style.backgroundColor = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.send();
        }
        changecolor();
    </script>
    <button type="button" onclick="changecolor();">Request Color</button>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $list = array('red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'pink', 'green');

$i = array_rand($list);
$color = $list[$i];
echo $color;
?>
```

Comment: fixed the color to background color which I missed as part of the instructions of what he was looking for.

Comment: I just tested it and it worked.  Retry it to make sure that you did not copy it before I fixed a couple of typos with the original post.  Also xhttp.open("GET", "color-service.php", true); only works if the color-service.php is in the same folder as the html.  You may need to change the target if it's in a different folder

Comment: Are you getting a console error in your browser?  If you JavaScript is failing somewhere else in your application, it can cause your whole page to stop working.  Server configuration could also be an issue if PHP is not enabled or something like that. Can you share the URL you are testing on?

Comment: I also just noticed that you might be trying to populate your <p> tag with the text name of the color, in which case, you'd also need to add the line document.getElementById('color').innerText = this.responseText; right next to the line that changes the background color.